# How this switch button work by CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

Can anyone explain how the cool turn on/off switch button worked?http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/

I would like to set a prevention check to see whether the user really want to switch the button. Such as

```
$(document).on('change', '.onoffswitch',function(event){...

http://jsfiddle.net/aGZ7Y/2/
```

As you can see, the change event has triggered but did not stop the switch behavior.

This is simply done by pure css.
I even do not know why a change would be triggered after clicking the button.
(since I found the checkbox has been set to display:none)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use click handler that too on the label element not in the div element

The [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change) is fired after the value is changed so it is not a cancelable event.

```
$(document).on('click', '.onoffswitch-label', function (event) {
    if (!confirm("sure to switch?")) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c73Yw/)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is basically remove the CSS code that make the changes ON/OFF when triggered and add them to your JQuery code.
You already catching the event in JQuery, now simply change the CSS accordingly from your code.

The checkbox has been set to `display:none;` to hide the original checkbox (this ugly grey box with the tick...).
On top on that (which is on `display:none;`) we are 'building' the new custom one...